# Ruby on Rails 4 date_field doesn't seem to render

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

I am building a form using Ruby on Rails 4. My model has a `dob` attribute that is a `date` in the database. My _form.html.erb has an excerpt like this:

```
<div class="control-group">
    <%= f.label :dob, :class => 'control-label' %>
    <div class="controls">
      <%= f.date_field :dob %>
    </div>
  </div>
```

For whatever reason, the HTML gets rendered as a regular input text box. Is there something being done wrong here?

Comment: What browser do you use? Actually date_field is a text field with built in browser date select menu. If yours doesn't support that functionality it will render simple text field.

Comment: I found that `f.date_field` works with Chrome but not with Firefox..
so definetly it is browser dependent.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Try

`<%= f.date_select :dob %>`

See more [here](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/DateHelper.html) on date fields.